# using mdframed with multicol causes some sort of overflow

Tags: multicol, mdframed

I'm trying to make a cheatsheet in the style of the [OpenGL Quick Reference Card](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl-quick-reference-card.pdf) by using multicol and mdframed. It seems to work fine, but at times mdframed's frames are seemingly-randomly cut off, wasting most of a page. [This is my source,](http://pastebin.com/La87E4QW) [this is the output](http://feephome.no-ip.org/~feep/latex_broken.pdf).

I'm using Gentoo's texlive-2012, which has an outdated `mdframed`; when I switch to the current version of `mdframed`, [it looks like this](http://feephome.no-ip.org/~feep/latex_broken2.pdf). Note how page three is almost empty despite the absence of manual pagebreaks. I tried removing the `\section`s, but that made no difference. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Add a `\clearpage` at line 397. Before the statement `\begin{segment}{Function Declarations}` starts.

Comment: That works, thank you! I'm still wondering what's wrong with the packages, though ..

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on you code. You have to adjust it manually because `section` has some glue dimension. Add a `\clearpage` at line 397. Before the statement `\begin{segment}{Function Declarations}` starts.